# Execution plan Key Lookup on clustered index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I know that Key Lookup can be resolved by adding the column to include list on a nonclustered index, but I have a query that the query optimizer use the  clustered index and displays Key Lookup.

Why is that? The clustered index contains all the columns... and how I can fix it?

Comment: Can you paste execution plan as xml in some paste bin and give the link

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. This is a product specific question.

Comment: i am using mssql 2014

Comment: basically column in select statement should be in include list,you should not add the column in select statement to the index

Comment: The Key Lookup might not actually be on the part of the query which uses the clustered index - but without execution plan - it's impossible to say.